# Get back UIImage data after saving it to photo Library in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I got an issue after saving an image created by my app into iPhone Library and trying to get it back. Image data are differents.

**Create Image**

1.Code

I create an image without using alpha (In fact I got the same result if I use alpha)

```
+ (UIImage *)createImageFromData:(NSData *)data {
    uint8_t *imageData = (uint8_t *) calloc(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3, sizeof(uint8_t));
    [data getBytes:imageData];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                              imageData,
                                                              WIDTH * HEIGHT * 3,
                                                              NULL);
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(WIDTH,
                                        HEIGHT,
                                        8, // Bits per color component
                                        3 * 8, // Bits per pixel : 1 pixel => 3 component
                                        3 * WIDTH, // bytes per lign (1 byte = 1 component)
                                        colorSpace,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        NO,
                                        renderingIntent);
    UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    return resultImage;
}
```

2.Debug

Here what I got with lldb when I put breaking at the end of the method

```
(lldb) p (int)imageData[0]
(uint8_t) $0 = 102
(lldb) p (int)imageData[1]
(uint8_t) $1 = 116
(lldb) p (int)imageData[2]
(uint8_t) $2 = 121
(lldb) p (int)imageData[3]
(uint8_t) $3 = 112
```

**Saving Image**

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_image, self,
   @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
```

EDIT : I tried an alternative way to save the image :

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.generatedImageView.image.CGImage));
uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
NSData *dataToSave = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:CFDataGetLength(pixelData) freeWhenDone:NO];

ALAssetsLibrary *assetLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[assetLib writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:dataToSave metadata:nil completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

`DataToSave` got the right number of bytes, both `error` and `assetURL` are nil in the completion block, and I can't see any new image in the photos album

**Get back image from Library**

This a delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    // Handle a still image picked from a photo album
    if (CFStringCompare ((CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeImage, 0)
    == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
        self.image = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Getting back data from previous image**

1.Code

```
+ (NSData *)createDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];

    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:SIZE freeWhenDone:YES];;
}
```

2.Debug

Now what I have

```
(lldb) p (int)data[0]
(int) $4 = 35
(lldb) p (int)data[1]
(int) $5 = 72
(lldb) p (int)data[2]
(int) $6 = 100
(lldb) p (int)data[3]
(int) $7 = 255
```

An alpha component appears with a value of 255 ... this should not be a problem ? But all others value have changed. And I really don't know how to get the previous value at this point !

EDIT : It seems to be an compression (when saving image) and decompression (when getting it back) problem.
But I need to get the exact same data after saving it in the Photos album.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is compressed to JPEG before it is saved to photo album. And is decompressed when you are loading it. JPEG is lossy compression. So when you are comparing pixel-data you have differences between original image and compressed/decompressed.

To save lossless try following:

```
+ (void)saveImageData:(NSData *)data {
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLib = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
    [assetLib writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:data metadata:nil completionBlock:nil];
}
```

For more information about lossless saving/loading to/from photo album please read this thread [Saving to/getting JPEG from user gallery without recompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150017/saving-to-getting-jpeg-from-user-gallery-without-recompression)

Comment: In this case, is there a way to save it without compression ?

Comment: @KIDdAe was my answer helpful? You should know what to do in this case :)

Comment: I'll give you a feedback as soon as I give it a try (hope I'll have time this evening) ! This is a promess :) !

Comment: When using `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:` I don't even see the photos being added in the photos album (but it work when using others ALAssetLibrary method like `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`)

Comment: I was using ALAssetLibrary but I am not familiar with it. This was the reason why I have posted also a link to another thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150017/saving-to-getting-jpeg-from-user-gallery-without-recompression . I hope you could find solution there. Also it could be a good idea to start a new topic and post your not-working code there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manage a file compare process with saved photos album images because, It automatically embeds few more details with your saved image such as details about location, time etc... when you are saving an image to the photo library. So it will not be same as your input image after the retrieval.

Comment: I don't think those have any impact when I got back the pixel Data (since I have the same number of bytes + alpha channel) and I got the value 255 every 4 bytes from the beginning (if there was a header it won't be the case)