# NSData -> UIImage -> NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

After doing something like

```
NSData *originalImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"somefolder\somepicture.jpg"];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:originalImageData];
```

Is there any way to get the actual NSData back from the UIImage object?

The function

```
NSData *newImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 1.0);
```

does not return the same NSData, which I believe is due to compression (or lack thereof). I suppose this might work for a .png file (no compression), but .pngs are much larger and not fit for use for what I am doing.

In the end, I am mostly just looking for a way to make

```
[newImageData isEqualToData:originalImageData]
```

evaluate to true.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just store the original data if that's what you need later?

Comment: At best you will get an image file with the same quality as the original.  There's no practical way to come close to generating an identical file, except in special cases.  (If you want to compare images, compare the images, not the files.  Even then there's apt to be some mismatch, but you can use a compare scheme that tolerates minor differences.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way to get original data from image. You have to store data somewhere if you will need it later.

You can take a look at this topics to get a little more information about image processing in iOS:

[Saving to/getting JPEG from user gallery without recompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150017/saving-to-getting-jpeg-from-user-gallery-without-recompression)

[Get back UIImage data after saving it to photo Library in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838461/get-back-uiimage-data-after-saving-it-to-photo-library-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

May be it could be better to store the Hash (MD5) of your image, and compare on 2 Hash... You can create a MD5UIImage Inherit from UIImage with a property to store the MD5 + a NSData+MD5 category to calc the MD5... Google "NSDATA+MD5" for exemples...

Answer (score 0):

Why even use `dataWithContentsOfFile`?  Just use `imageNamed:` as:

```
// Returns the image object associated with the specified filename.

+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
```

like:

```
{
  UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"somepicture.jpg"]
  // …
}
```

where you need to be sure your image file is in the main bundle.  You've also got:

```
// Creates and returns an image object by loading the image data from the file at the specified path.

+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

which presumably relaxes the 'main bundle' limitation.